# Copy tracking settings to selected trackers?

Tags: workflow, tracking

It seems the *Copy to selected* option is not available in the *Movie clip editor*.

Is it possible to copy tracker settings from the active tracker to selected trackers? If so, how?

Comment: Are trackers pydata? Seems like you should/might be able to iterate and manually copy the "settings" you want.

Comment: @WChargin Sure enough, [they are](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/search.html?q=tracking+marker). Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following script to copy a given set of properties from the active tracking marker to the selected markers.

Paste this into a text editor, modify the values at the top, and press *<kbd>Run Script</kbd>* to run it.

```
############################################################
# Define your constants here                               #
to_set   = ('color', 'hide')  # list of properties to set  #
mc_name  = 'SomeMovie.mp4'    # name of movie clip         #
obj_name = 'Camera'           # name of track              #
############################################################

clips  = bpy.data.movieclips
clip = clips[mc_name]
obj = clip.tracking.objects[obj_name]
tracks = obj.tracks

# find the active track
active = tracks.active

# define a set of attributes to change
new_values = { k : getattr(active, k) for k in to_set }

# loop through and assign
for track in tracks:
  if not track.select:
      continue
  for k, v in new_values.items():
    setattr(track, k, v)
```

You can use [this API page](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.MovieTrackingMarker.html) to find the names of the properties you want to set.